# Sublime Text 3: Anaconda show lint errors hotkey?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-anaconda

How do I add a hotkey to view lint errors? It shows me that there is an error, but doesn't tell me what it is. If I want to see the errors I have to

right click -> Anaconda -> show error list

which seems very inconvenient. I think it would be nice to have a panel on the bottom with all the lint errors showing or at the very least add a hotkey to toggle the errors menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just move the cursor to the line that is giving you the error, you get a complete description of what the error is in the Sublime Text 3 status bar.

Apart from that, you can set the option `anaconda_linter_show_errors_on_save` as `true` (it's `false` by default) to force anaconda to show you the errors list quickpanel everytime that you save the file.

Comment: its does not show error when i hover to the error line. Please help!

Answer (score 12):

Open the Sublime console and type

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

Then

right click -> Anaconda -> show error list

Look in the console for the command-name, and add it to your

Preferences > Key Bindings - User

```
{ "keys": ["shift+f12"], "command": "COMMAND_NAME" },
```

Turn off logging with

```
sublime.log_commands(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, not ideal but still quicker, is to `ctrl+shift+p` followed by typing `error` followed by `enter`. This will show you the anaconda errors.

Answer (score 0):

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+keypad8"], "command": "anaconda_disable_linting" },`

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+keypad9"], "command": "anaconda_enable_linting" }`